# Fazer IF para dar SlideUp em um elemento

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
<div class="unidadesTotal">
    <div class="unidades">tituloSYS</div>
    <div style="display:none" class="unidadesConteudo margin-top-25">
        <div class="margin-left-10">    <span>descricaoSYS</span>

        </div>
        <div class="atendimento unidadesAtendimento margin-top-15 f-left">hor&aacute;rio de atendimento</div>   <a href="codigoSYS" target="_blank"><div class="unidadesAtendimento unidadesLocalizacao margin-top-15 margin-left-10 f-left">ver localiza&ccedil;&atilde;o</div></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

O `unidadesTotal` é um botão, quando eu clico nele o `unidadesConteudo` deixa der ser **display:none** e passa a ser **display:block**, até ai perfeito, aqui está meu Jquery:

```
$('.unidadesTotal').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.unidades').addClass('unidadesHover');
    $(this).parent().find('.unidadesConteudo').slideDown();
});
```

Como eu faria um IF para o botão dar um **slideUp**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você simplesmente pode verificar se há a classe que você adiciona ao realizar o `.slideDown()` que é a classe `unidadesHover` e então você faz um `if` que realiza o `.slideDown()` caso esta classe exista, e remove-a.

```js
$('.unidadesTotal').click(function () {
    var unidades         = $(this).parent().find('.unidades');
    var unidadesConteudo = $(this).parent().find('.unidadesConteudo');
    if(unidades.hasClass('unidadesHover')){ //se houver a classe .unidadesHover
      unidades.removeClass('unidadesHover');
      unidadesConteudo.slideUp();  
    }else{
      unidades.addClass('unidadesHover');
      unidadesConteudo.slideDown();  
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="unidadesTotal">
    <div class="unidades">tituloSYS</div>
    <div style="display:none" class="unidadesConteudo margin-top-25">
        <div class="margin-left-10">    <span>descricaoSYS</span>

        </div>
        <div class="atendimento unidadesAtendimento margin-top-15 f-left">hor&aacute;rio de atendimento</div>   <a href="codigoSYS" target="_blank"><div class="unidadesAtendimento unidadesLocalizacao margin-top-15 margin-left-10 f-left">ver localiza&ccedil;&atilde;o</div></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: O `!$` é o "senão", né? não trabalhei com ele ainda, com Jquery.

Comment: o `!` é um operador que **nega** a condição posterior, por ex.: `if (!true)` significa `false` e `if(!false)` significa `true`

Comment: Você também poderia inverter as coisas, remover o `!` e trocar os códigos de lugar um com o outro, deixando o `.slideDown()` no `else` e o `.slideUp()` no `if`, também funciona :D

Comment: Editei a resposta para que fique de melhor entendimento para você.

Comment: A explicação ficou perfeita!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o seletor `:visited` para checar se o elemento está visível ou não (que é o que o `slideUp()` e o `slideDown()` fazem: eles modificam a visibilidade do elemento). Por questões de performance, preferi optar por guardar a referência do elemento em uma variável, mas funcionaria sem ela.

```js
$('.unidadesTotal').click(function () {
    var unidadesConteudo = $(this).parent().find('.unidadesConteudo');
    $(this).parent().find('.unidades').addClass('unidadesHover');
  
    if(unidadesConteudo.is(':visible')) {
      unidadesConteudo.slideUp();
    } else {
      unidadesConteudo.slideDown();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="unidadesTotal">
    <div class="unidades">tituloSYS</div>
    <div style="display:none" class="unidadesConteudo margin-top-25">
        <div class="margin-left-10">    <span>descricaoSYS</span>

        </div>
        <div class="atendimento unidadesAtendimento margin-top-15 f-left">hor&aacute;rio de atendimento</div>   <a href="codigoSYS" target="_blank"><div class="unidadesAtendimento unidadesLocalizacao margin-top-15 margin-left-10 f-left">ver localiza&ccedil;&atilde;o</div></a>

    </div>
</div>
```